# PHP var->Javascript->PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a project that has the following problem:

The database gives(via php) an array with a list of JavaScript files that need to be loaded. it is stored in the variable `$array(php)`. I need to extract those source files with `php(foreach loop)` and load them via JavaScript. It is like this:

```
document.write("<?php foreach($js_files as $filename) {if( trim($filename) <> "" ){echo '<script     type=\'text/javascript\' src=$filename></script> \n';}} ?> ");
```

The problem is that it loads a couple of files but goes wrong with the first one(a google api file). Does anyone have a sollution to this? Or any ideas in which direction i have to look.

Comment: I think a solution to this would be to change your approach altogether.

Comment: `echo '<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=$filename></script> \n'`

Willn't work. You need use doublequotes to use variables ($filename) inline. If you use single quotes `$filename` will be just a string, not variable.

Comment: it is not possible to change my approach. De database i am working on gives a list of resources that has to be loaded. The output format is an array. I need to load the files when the callback function is triggerd

Answer (score 1):

If the code needs to be fired from a JavaScript function then you can get rid of the document.write, in favor of creating new script objects, and appending to the head tag.

```
<?php
  foreach($js_files as $filename){
    if(trim($filename) != ''){
      echo 'var s = document.createElement("script");';
      echo 's.type = "text/javascript";';
      echo 's.src = "' . $filename . '";';
      echo 'document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);'
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: This has to trigger in a javascript callback function, so i don't think this is a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea on multiple levels, but can be fairly easily resolved. But first:
1) Never use `document.write()`. To dynamically load a script it is better to use:

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); //create a script element
script.src = 'javascript.js'; //path to src file
//now get the body element and append the new script element
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

2) Loading scripts like this will likely not work if they need to be loaded in a particular order, as the downloading of dynamic scripts occurs asynchronously (non-deterministic)

3) Generally speaking, you should concatenate your `js` files to reduce `http` requests, you can use a tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to make an automatic build process.

4) If you really, really want those scripts to be dynamically loaded though, you can use the process I outlined in (1) to get the file names use `ajax`:

```
//depends on jQuery, but could be written vanilla if needed
$.get('myPhp.php', function(resp){
    var arr = resp.split(','); //splits returned string on the comma
    var i = arr.length;
    //iterate through the results set
    while (i--) {
        //do process from (1) above
    }
});
```

Note that this will still have the unordered problem. If you need sequential dynamic loading check out something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the code "" in `if( trim($filename) <> "" )` because the `"` breaks the javascript string.

Comment: How does the escape here works? I keeps giving me errors

Comment: Remove the 'document.write(" ")' wrapping as +MrCode said, and  drop the src with ""

Comment: Javascript is processed client side, when php is processed on server side, so it can't work as you expect

Comment: i dont think im getting the problem clear. PHP loads the file list from the database when it is started. This list must be exposded(loaded) when a certain javascript callback is executed!